# Issue when fetching the Query String : Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**In my request class I have below code.**

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $instance = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $instance->after(function ($validator) {
        $this->CheckRoleExists($validator);
    });
    return $instance;
}

public function CheckRoleExists($validator)
{
    dd($_SERVER);
}
```

**I am trying to print the Query string and I am getting below.**

```
"QUERY_STRING" => ""
```

**and Url is below.**

```
"REQUEST_URI" => "/Learning/public/UpdateRole/1"
```

**My Route is below**

```
Route::put('/UpdateRole/{RoleID}',array('uses' => 'Role@update', 'as' => 'UpdateRole'));
```

In the above Request Url: 1 is Query String. As we can see Query String value is showing null when I check it like this `dd($_SERVER);`

Please guide me to get the Query string correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Request::segment(1);`

That should do the trick.

Comment: My side it works `Request::segment(2);` for this. But Is there any way which is not a work around?

Comment: Yeah, it should be `Request::segemnt(2);`. This is actually not a work around. Laravel uses this internally to get request segments.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `query` by doing the following, I believe. Haven't fully tested. Add to your `getValidatorInstance()` method:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $instance = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $instance->after(function ($validator) {
        $this->CheckRoleExists($validator);
    });

    // this here:
    return $this->query(); // or $this->all()

    ...
}
```